# Seaborn FacetGrid Error: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, visualization, data-analysis

I'm trying to create a Seaborn FacetGrid to generate scatter plots based on the 'trans_type' variable in my dataset, but I'm encountering an error related to 'DataFrame' object and 'iteritems.' Here's my code:

```
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fuel_econ = pd.read_csv('data/fuel-econ.csv')

sedan_classes = ['Minicompact Cars', 'Subcompact Cars', 'Compact Cars', 'Midsize Cars', 'Large Cars']

vclasses = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(ordered = True, categories = sedan_classes)
fuel_econ['trans_type'] = fuel_econ['trans'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])

# Create a FacetGrid for plotting multiple subplots based on the 'trans_type' variable.
g = sb.FacetGrid(data=fuel_econ_subset, hue='trans_type', hue_order=['Automatic', 'Manual'], height=4, aspect=1.5)

# Use the 'map' function to create scatter plots within each facet.
# 'sb.regplot' is used to create the scatter plots.
# 'displ' is on the x-axis, 'comb' on the y-axis.
# 'fit_reg' is set to False, so there's no regression line in the scatter plots.
g.map(sb.regplot, 'displ', 'comb', fit_reg=False)

# Add a legend to the FacetGrid to distinguish between 'Automatic' and 'Manual' transmissions.
g.add_legend()

# Set the x-axis label for all subplots.
plt.xlabel('Displacement(1)')

# Set the y-axis label for all subplots.
plt.ylabel('Combine Fuel Eff. (mpg)')
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error related to 'iteritems.' My DataFrame ('fuel_econ_subset') appears to have the necessary columns, but I'm encountering this issue. How can I resolve this error and successfully create scatter plots using Seaborn's FacetGrid?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHyIz.png)
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data of the Dataframe and full traceback.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHyIz.png

Comment: Probably the problem is about pandas version. Because iteritems was removed in pandas 2.0. Take a look https://github.com/YosefLab/Compass/issues/92#issuecomment-1679190560

Comment: Update seaborn and pandas. Also, you should be using `sns.lmplot`, not `FacetGrid` with `regplot`: _When using seaborn functions that infer semantic mappings from a dataset, care must be taken to synchronize those mappings across facets (e.g., by defining the hue mapping with a palette dict or setting the data type of the variables to category). In most cases, it will be better to use a figure-level function (e.g. relplot() or catplot()) than to use FacetGrid directly._